# Bash copy with special characters

Tags: bash, special-characters, cp

I have a file named Test_File@!@#~:"_1328853976191.txt in tmp directory

I am running the following code

```
#!/bin/sh


for f in /tmp/*.azw2; do
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      cp "$f" /some/directory
   fi

done
```

It throws error

cp: cannot remove '/some/directory/Test_File@!@#~:"_1328853976191.txt': No such file or directory

This works if destination is either / or a directory under root, but not in any directory 2 level deep.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What platform are you on?  That is not a normal error message from cp.  But the problem is likely that the destination directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @evil otto  I am on linux , destination directory is present

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete explanation, but the exclamation point in the file name makes me think that turning history expansion off (using `set +H`) might help.